# Docker containers won't start again after being stopped

Tags: docker, gitlab, qnap, gitea

I'm trying to launch a GitLab or Gitea docker container in my QNAP NAS (Container Station) and, for some reason, when I restart the container, it won't start back up because files are lost (it seems).

For example, for GitLab it gives me errors saying `runsvdir-start` and `gitlab-ctl` don't exist. For Gitea it's the `s6-supervise` file.

Now I am launching the container like this, just to keep it simple:

```
docker run -d --privileged --restart always gitea/gitea:latest
```

A simple `docker stop ....` and `docker start ....` breaks it. How do I troubleshoot something like this?

Comment: I have precisely the same issue with container station and Gitea.
A similar issue also occurs with GitLab CE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QNAP has sent this issue to R&D and they were able to replicate it. It's a bug and will probably be fixed in a new Container Station update.

---

It's now fixed in QTS 4.3.6.20190906 and later.

Comment: Do you have a case/issue tracker that we can use to follow the bug?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I'm communicating via a private support ticket and I'm waiting on an update right now. I'll update this post when they fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Normal to lose you data if you launch just :

```
docker run -d --privileged --restart always gitea/gitea:latest
```

You should use VOLUME to sharing folder between your host and docker host for example :

```
docker run -d --privileged -v ./gitea:/data -p 3000:3000 -p 222:22 --restart always gitea/gitea:latest
```

Or use docker-compose.yml (see the [official docs](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/install-with-docker/)).

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it. I was using volumes all the time. The volume data is kept, but after a restart, it still says that the s6-supervise file is missing.

Comment: You had test without using --privileged
Running a container with the --privileged flag gives all the capabilities to the container and also access to the host’s devices (everything that is under the /dev folder).

Comment: I have tested with and without the privileged flag.